# Receive data only from the selected item on another page

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I would like that when I click on any item in my list, only show the data of this item on the new page. I can already display the items from page 1 to page 2, but I can not filter. Could someone help me with this?

HTML p1

```
  <ion-segment-button value="Todosgastronomia" class="todos-button" 
   (click)="selecionaprodutoscategoria(1)">
   Todos
  </ion-segment-button>


    <ion-list *ngSwitchCase="'Todosgastronomia'">
    <ion-item no-lines *ngFor="let produto of 
    produtos(click)="querocomprar()" no-padding>
    <ion-thumbnail item-start>
    <img src="assets/imgs/mmsszjm.png" class="imgast">
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <ion-row class="rowclass">
    <h3 class="nomproduto"> {{produto.nom_produto}} </h3>
    <h3 class="nomsubcategoria">{{produto.nom_subcategoria}} </h3>
    <h3 class="descproduto"> {{produto.desc_produto}} </h3>
    <h3 class="descdesconto"> {{produto.desc_desconto}}</h3>
    <h3 class="valproduto">
    <font color="#179c90">R$</font> {{produto.val_produto}}
    </h3>
    <button ion-button small end class="favproduto">
    <ion-icon name="icon-ico_favoritos"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <button ion-button class="querotodos">QUERO! 
    </button>
    </ion-row>
    </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

TS p1

```
 export class HomePage implements OnInit {
 videoOptions: VideoOptions;
 videoUrl: string;
 public regioes: Regiao[];
 produtos: Produto[];

 querocomprar(produto: number) {
this.navCtrl.push(ConteudoprodutoPage, {
  val: this.produtos
})
```

}

TS p2

```
export class ConteudoprodutoPage {

produto: Produto;

constructor(private payPal: PayPal, public navCtrl: NavController, public 
navParams: NavParams) {
this.produto = navParams.get("valor");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your `ion-item` just pass the `produto` as a param

```
<ion-item no-lines *ngFor="let produto of produtos" (click)="querocomprar(produto)" no-padding>
```

And on your `querocomprar()` method on HomePage, get the produto item

```
querocomprar(produto: any) {
this.navCtrl.push(ConteudoprodutoPage, {'val': produto})
}
```

Receive the `val` param data on your `ConteudoprodutoPage` class

```
constructor(private payPal: PayPal, public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.produto = navParams.get("val");
}
```